# Nodejs - Como utilizar variáveis externas em funções assíncronas

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, ejs

Estou iniciando em `node` e ainda acho o conceito de *funções assíncronas* complicado. Estou utilizando e `js` para renderizar `templates` para e-mail na minha aplicação.

O protótipo é:

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');

function EmailManager(){
  this.configs ={};
  this.receivers = "";
  this.subject = "";
  this.template="";
  this.context ={};

};

EmailManager.prototype.send = function(){

    ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname,'..','templates',this.template),this.context, function(err, data) {

        if(err){
                 throw err;
        }

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(this.configs);

        var mailOptions = {
                from: '"'+ this.configs.sender 
                + ' <'+ this.configs.user +'>', // sender address
                to: this.receivers, // list of receivers
                subject: this.subject, 
              }; 

        mailOptions.html = data;


        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
              if(error){
                 throw error;
              }
              //console.log('Message sent to '+ this.receivers+", subject: "+ this.subject);
        });

     });

};
```

Para executar, eu crio uma nova instância, configuro todos as variáveis internas e executo `send()` em seguida. Porém, quando executo aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> error TypeError: Cannot read property 'configs' of undefined
>   (node:9820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Cannot read property 'configs'
>   of undefined

Ao que parece a referência `this` é perdida dentro da função assíncrona, li que funções do tipo desconsideram o contexto externo. Então como poderia passar esta referência para o meu método? Também tive este mesmo problema com outras funções parecidas.

Answer (score 2):

Como sugeriste o contexto de execução (o `this`)  não é o esperado. Há algumas ferramentas para corrigir isso. Os dois sítios onde isso pode acontecer é na própria função `.send()` e depois dentro da callback do método `ejs.renderFile`.

Partindo do principio que o contexto do `this` dentro do `.send()` é correto (caso não seja tens de mostrar como estás a correr esse código), podes fazer de duas maneiras para forçar o `this` à instancia de `EmailManager` dentro da callback:

#### Usando `.bind()`:

```
ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'templates', this.template), this.context, function(err, data) {
    // ... o código dentro da callback
}.bind(this)); // <--- usando ".bind()"
```

#### Usando `self`, uma referência do `this`:

Podes criar uma variável com o nome `self` para ser uma referência, ponteiro, do da instância de `EmailManager`. Nesse caso seria assim:

```
EmailManager.prototype.send = function() {
    var self = this; // <-- agora podes usar o "self" em vêz do "this"
    
    ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'templates', self.template), self.context, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(self.configs);
        var mailOptions = {
            from: '"' + self.configs.sender + ' <' + self.configs.user + '>', // sender address
            to: self.receivers, // list of receivers
            subject: self.subject,
        };
        mailOptions.html = data;
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('Message sent to '+ self.receivers+", subject: "+ self.subject);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: fazer uso da arrow function ali não iria dar o contexto certo à função? (eu pergunto porque ele tá a usar ES6 e NodeJS)

Comment: @MoshMage sim talvez seja seja uma opção. Mas como o AP não usa Classes ES6 deduzi que tem uma versão de Node antiga, pré ES6. Olhando melhor vejo uso de `const`... mas depende de como é chamado o código.

Comment: Como lá vi `const` no inicio, fiquei na duvida

Comment: @MoshMage é vi agora também, a tempo de editar o meu comentário.  Seria interessante ver como `EmailManager.prototype.send` é chamado para ter a certeza.